# How can I convert a i18next localized string to UpperCase

Tags: angularjs, gsp, i18next

I am working on a UI project using Groovy on Grails and `AngularJS`. For localization/internationalization we are using `ng-i18next`.

Here I have a requirement to display the localized text in uppercase. There is a anchor tag in my `.gsp` file

```
<a ng-href="${request.contextPath}/#/list">{{'locales.data.labels.summary' | i18next}}</a>
```

This displays the text "Summary" after rendering in browser whereas we want to display it as "SUMMARY".

I think there should be a filter which can convert the text in uppercase after translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `uppercase` filter

```
 {{'locales.data.labels.summary' | i18next | uppercase}}
```

Ref# http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_uppercase

OR

You can use CSS style for this

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

Ref# CSS text-transform Property

Comment: it looks like that the i18next team doesn't provide a way to do that. https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/765. You may define a new key with a given transformation/formatting like uppercase... see this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-g1d47?file=/src/i18n.js:342-350. also there people start to use workarounds like this: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1034